# How to set acknowledgement to false in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want messages not to be removed from topic when they are consumed by setting acknowledgement to false in Kafka. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Messages aren't removed from Kafka topics once they're consumed; that's not how Kafka works. Kafka just tracks the offset in the log up to which a particular consumer has read.

If you want to re-consume messages then your Consumer can simply request a messages from the desired offset in the log.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the code for requesting a messages from the desired offset in the log or resetting the offset?

Comment: https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/648  You can do something like this to read from offset.  Language used is python and driver is dpkp/kafka-python